# By default android creating new project as ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I recently updated eclipse, SDK and my problems are

1. By default it takes `fragment_main.xml`
2. Extends default activity to `ActionBarActivity`
3. By default it is adding the library `appcompat 7`

I dont have any issues with adding the library, but when i am trying to run then it is not executing in the device(2.3 android). I noticed it and changed to Activity.

If i extends it to Activity and run it and again for the next time the same problem arises while creating new Activity like...

> Creating 2 xml files with extending ActionBarActiity.

I just want the new class to extend `Activity` but not `ActionBarActivity` where my target device is 2.3 and above without downgrading it

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity and provides a nice bar(hehe) above your layout. Your editor is doing it correctly. ActionBarActivity was added in newer version of the sdk and it was added in the support library for older versions using appcompact v7(api 8). So most probably your development enviroment is correct. My guess is you need to check your imports and import ActionBarActivity from the support package.

Comment: I have created an activity it automatically creating 2 layouts how to avoid it(`fragment layout`)

Comment: those layouts could be in different folders like layout and layout-land?? though I have never encountered this problem before

Comment: If i create new Activity by clicking `new Activity --> Blank Activity` then takes as `LayoutName activity_main` and `fragmentLayoutName fragment_main` But here I dont need the fragmentLayoutName and it extends as actionBarActivity. So that every time I was deleting all the things for proper structure

Answer (score 0):

It comes in SDK v4.4 . It is a plus point for developers because developers don't need to manually add the ActionBarActivity into their project. There are two solutions for your problem.

1. Downgrade your SDK to 4.3 or lower.
       **or**
2. Remove ActionBarActivity and extends Activity in your java file.

Both will work for you.

Comment: Is it manditory that each time while creating activity we should change the code and delete the fragment layout