# Android build version and minSDKVersion in Android Studio

Tags: android, api, android-min-sdk

I have read other answers in context of "**What is minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion?**" on SO and those were good enough for understanding but they talked about eclipse, not that it really matters that much.

Anyway, I wanted to ask in context of Android Studio, that when creating new app, it asks for `minSDKVersion` only but no `targetSDKVersion` as it used to do in Eclipse. Why is this? Is it insignificant?

The other thing I wanted to ask is, when I did create a new app infact with `minSDKVersion` as IceCreamSandwich(4.0.3), the class `MyActivity` extended  from `ActionBarActivity` and not from `Activity`. Why is this happening?
Are minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion equal in this case? and if this is the case, Would I get the base class as `Activity`if I were to change the `targetSDKVersion` explicitly to say, API 21?

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio, everything turns around Gradle.

Your `build.gradle` file has this in it:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'your.package.name'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22 // default is latest
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Here you can see the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

Nothing is required in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file anymore, regarding API levels.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your `Activity` issue: 
`ActionBarActivity` is a child class of `Activity`. 
`ActionBarActivity` is given automatically provided as it's the newest support tool available w.r.t. the `minSDKVersion`. If you simply want to use `Activity`, just change it in the code and remove unused methods.

Comment: I just checked in gradle script, minSDKVersion=15(ICS). So, should I conclude that if my base class is ActionBarActivity, it is according to ICS and if I were to change the minSDKVersion to JellyBean, would it be Activity?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516578/by-default-android-creating-new-project-as-actionbaractivity :

"
    1. Downgrade your SDK to 4.3 or lower. or
    2. Remove ActionBarActivity and extends Activity in your java file.
"